# how to compare current line with next line in a csv and display the column difference in unix scripting

Tags: shell-script, awk

file.csv

```
ABC,EFG,22  
XYZ,MNO,24  
XYZ,MNO,228
SPOT,ID,NUMBER
SPOT,ID,VARCHAR2
INF,SUMMARY,VARCHAR2
INF,SUMMARY,NUMBER
```

I want to compare first line with second line and display ABC and XYZ are different and second and third line comparison should bring 24 is the old value and 228 is the new value

Similar comparison of column wise if its different then print the values.
I have trouble in comparing current row with previous record

I am able compare for the same line. Below worked for me to some extent on the same row but to check for previous row i couldn't.

```
awk -F: '{if(!($1==$2||$2==$3||$3==$1))printf("%s","not ");print"matched",$0}' file.csv
```

i also tried with while loop for reading and comparing by assigning the value to another variable.

```
x=""
while IFS= , read -r a b c
do
 if [a == x]]
then
 echo "$a"
x=$a
done < input.csv
```

Comment: This does not look like a question showing any effort from author. If you need somebody to do your work than you should place advertisement with job spec and pay rate.

Comment: If you have any ideas how to solve your problem yourself you should show the ideas or your attempted solution that may not work. At least you should specify your requirements as detailed as possible. This is not very clear: "Similar comparison of column wise if its different then print the values". I suggest to show a longer example input that covers all possible cases and the corresponding expected output. Please [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: I have no idea what this sentence should mean: "I want to compare first line with second line and display ABC and XYZ are different and second and third line comparison should bring 24 is the old value and 228 is the new value". Probably even Google translate would do a better translation job. And your code is obviously broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR > 1 {
    if (p[0] != $0) {
        printf "\nLine %d (%s) != %d (%s)\n", NR-1, p[0], NR, $0
    }
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (p[i] != $i) {
            printf "\tField %d.%d (%s) != %d.%d (%s)\n", NR-1, i, p[i], NR, i, $i
        }
    }
}
{ split($0,p); p[0]=$0 }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv

Line 1 (ABC,EFG,22) != 2 (XYZ,MNO,24)
        Field 1.1 (ABC) != 2.1 (XYZ)
        Field 1.2 (EFG) != 2.2 (MNO)
        Field 1.3 (22) != 2.3 (24)

Line 2 (XYZ,MNO,24) != 3 (XYZ,MNO,228)
        Field 2.3 (24) != 3.3 (228)

Line 3 (XYZ,MNO,228) != 4 (SPOT,ID,NUMBER)
        Field 3.1 (XYZ) != 4.1 (SPOT)
        Field 3.2 (MNO) != 4.2 (ID)
        Field 3.3 (228) != 4.3 (NUMBER)

Line 4 (SPOT,ID,NUMBER) != 5 (SPOT,ID,VARCHAR2)
        Field 4.3 (NUMBER) != 5.3 (VARCHAR2)

Line 5 (SPOT,ID,VARCHAR2) != 6 (INF,SUMMARY,VARCHAR2)
        Field 5.1 (SPOT) != 6.1 (INF)
        Field 5.2 (ID) != 6.2 (SUMMARY)

Line 6 (INF,SUMMARY,VARCHAR2) != 7 (INF,SUMMARY,NUMBER)
        Field 6.3 (VARCHAR2) != 7.3 (NUMBER)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ed Morton.I was trying without array and splitting the line into columns, looping as I am new to Unix scripting. Your response has helped me to replace 67 line code with 11 lines which i can't copy and display here due to virtual system issue.But this made my day!! Thank you once again..Keep rocking and inspire us!!